# Objective C iPhone Development, saving and retrieving an NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray, xcode4.2

I am new to iPhone development and I am using XCode 4.2
I am trying to save an NSMutable array so that when I close the application and reopen it , the data will still be there
I am using these two functions :

```
-(void)saveData{
    [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:[data copy] toFile:[self dataFilePath]];
}
- (void)loadData
{
    data = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:self.dataFilePath];
}
```

but I found two major issues :
1- when I switch views and come back , the data is gone 
2- when I completely exit the application (i.e. I double click on the Main button and remove it from the list of running application) the data is not erased as well

I found that I can use these two NSMutableArray methods  : `writeToFile` and `initWithContentsOfFile`  but I don t know where to call them  (is it when I add items to the UITableView ? in the `viewDidLoad` ?

can somebody give me a sample code?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

For saving an array use `writeToFile:atomically:` method. It will save your `NSArray` content as plist file. For load an array from plist file, use `initWithContentsOfFile:` method.

Please note, that these methods will be able to save your stuff, only if your array has the following class instances `NSString`, `NSData`, `NSDate`, `NSNumber` `NSArray`, or `NSDictionary` as items.

you can call save/load methods like following

```
// in view controller implementation

- (void) saveData {
  [self.theArray writeToFile: self.filePath automatically:NO];
}

- (void) loadData {
  self.theArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile: self.filePath];
}

- (void) viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  [self loadData];
}

- (void) viewWillDisappear: (BOOL) animated {
  [super viewWillDisappear: animated];

  [self saveData];
}


// in the UIApplicationDelegate implementation
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
  [myCustomController saveData];
}
```

Comment: argh... i've copied that from documentation of [NSArray initWithContentsOfFile:] http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BABBGGGC - it has not full list, which is mentioned here http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-CBHBIGBI; i've updated answer with full list of supported classes

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when those 2 actions happen, saveData is not getting called. Therefore I would suggest saving your data on the AppDelegate on this method to solve problem 2 (exit app)

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
//Save data
}
```

As for problem 1 (when switching views), you just need to call your saveData on this method on your viewController:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
   //Save data
}
```

Hope that helps.